# Regex to extract a font family list from a CSS font declaration

Tags: .net, regex, csv

I am trying to create a .NET Regex to parse a CSS font declaration, which takes following form:

```
font: italic small-caps bold xx-small 3.0em "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
```

According to the CSS specification, all of the elements of the declared value are optional, and I have successfully created Regexes that match the first five elements (in all their different permitted forms), but I am having trouble creating a Regex that matches the list of font names, which is always the last element in the property value. I don't need to identify the individual elements in the font names list; I just want to match the list as a whole.

The font names list is comma separated list (with optional whitespace between elements) and each member of the list is either a single-word name or multiple words enclosed in quotes.

So far, I have come up with the following expression ...

```
(?<NAME_LIST>(?<QUOTED_NAME>"[\w ]+")|(?<SIMPLE_NAME>\w+)(?:,\s*(?<QUOTED_NAME>"\w ]+")|(?<SIMPLE_NAME>\w+))*)
```

... but it matches each member of the list individually, instead of matching the entire list.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this (assuming you already have some regex in place before this bit to match the stuff before the font list)?

```
(?<FONTS>(?:['"]?(?:\w+\s*)+["']?(?:,\s*|\s*;))+)
```

Note that this matches the semicolon at the end as well, but that can easily be trimmed off using string operations.

EDIT: Since you're only evaluating the value part of the declaration, you'll want this regex instead, which also has some fixes because of other problems I noticed with my original pattern.

```
(?<FONTS>(?:\s*(?:(?:['"](?:\w|\s)+["'])|\w+)\s*(?:,|$))+)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've accepted it, because it certainly matches the complete list of font names, which is more than I have achieved myself. However, I misled you a little ... the semicolon is not present in my input string because I am actually just parsing the value part of the declaration. I have removed the semicolon from your pattern and it still matches correctly. Am I likely to see any side effects from this usage? Thanks again.

Comment: @Tim: Yeah, it won't match the trailing font name, and I just discovered another problem with my regex that I hadn't noticed before (matches extra stuff at the beginning if the first font name isn't quoted), so I'm fixing it up now.

Comment: Okay, updated. (Had to step away from my computer for a bit while working on it.)

Comment: Thanks for the update - it passes my 49 unit tests so I guess it's a pretty robust solution! Thanks again for your help.